# case insensitive sort using spring data

Tags: spring-data-jpa

how can I do case insensitive sorting using Spring-data Pageable?

I have this method in my Repository

```
public interface ItemRepository extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Item>{
    @Query("SELECT o FROM Item o WHERE o.status = ?1")
    Page<Item> findByStatus(Item.Status status, Pageable pageable);
}
```

I want to be able to call that with:

```
itemRepository.findByStatus(Status.completed, new PageRequest(0, 10, Direction.ASC, "lower(name)")
```

Note the `lower` function in the property string. That doesn't work as Spring-data expects a property there. That will get translated to something like:

```
SELECT o FROM Item o WHERE o.status = ?1 ORDER BY o.lower(name)
```

which of course won't work as there is no 'lower' property on the object.

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`Sort.Order.ignoreCase()` was introduce around 8 months ago into spring-data-jpa, look here:

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAJPA-296

https://github.com/kraymondksc/spring-data-jpa/commit/c3adce0bd36799d3754a5f4c61aee64982abd7e0

Once you have an appropriate version of spring-data-jpa (I think since 1.4 M1, I have 1.4.1) you can write something like this:

```
Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.ASC, "name").ignoreCase();
itemRepository.findByStatus(Status.completed, new PageRequest(0, 10, new Sort(order));
```

Comment: Yep, that's how I've done it eventually. At the time there was a bug with that option. That's me reporting that there to be fixed :)

Comment: ``new Sort(order)`` constructor is deperecated, use this one ``new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.by(order))``

Comment: Is there a possibility also trim spaces before sorting? I need trim and ignore-case in order by added automatically.