# How can I Sort data Case insensitive with Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, spring, rest, sorting

I like to have a findAll Method in my SortimentRespository, which allows Sorting and Paging and where I can pass a parameter with the current page and the size of the page and the name of the column which I want to sort case insensitive.

The request shall look something like:

http://localhost:8081/x/rest/sortiments?size=20&page=1

or
http://localhost:8081/x/rest/sortiments?size=20&sort=name,desc&page=1

I tried the following methods in my Repository

```
    @Transactional
    public interface SortimentRepository extends JpaRepository<Sortiment,         RootKey>, SortimentRepositoryCustom {
        List<Sortiment> findAll();            
        // Query 1
        Page<Sortiment> findAllIgnoreCase(Pageable pageable);

        // Query 2
        Page<Sortiment> findAllByOrderByNameAscIgnoreCase(Pageable pageable);

        // Query 3
        @Query("select s from Sortiment s order by LOWER(s.name)")
        Page<Sortiment> findAllOrderByNameIgnoreCase(Pageable p);
    }
```

**Results**

Query 1:
Error while running: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sortimentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property find found for type Sortiment!

Query 2 :
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sortimentRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ignoreCase found for type Sortiment!

Query 3:
I even can't see this method in the hal browser under link search

Does anybody has an idea, how I could achieve the case insenstitive sorting? It would be as well be really nice, if I had something globale because several repository will need the case insensitive method for findAll...

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777638/case-insensitive-sort-using-spring-data

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, ensure that `Sortiment` bean is annotated with `@Entity`**

Spring data follows few rules (given in the below link) for the Repository method names and you need to change your query method as shown below:

**In Service layer:**

```
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(pageNumber,pageSize,Sort.Direction.ASC,name);
```

**Repository class:**

```
@Transactional
public interface SortimentRepository extends JpaRepository<Sortiment,RootKey>, 
     SortimentRepositoryCustom { 
        Page<Sortiment> findAll(Pageable pageable);
  }
```

You can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) for examples.

Comment: I've seen this, but the difference is, that I need ALL data and not a specific one with a given name.

Comment: I need all sortiments ordered in ignore case.  The standart sort is like:
Aa
Bb
aa
bb

and I need the data in the order like this:
Aa
aa
Bb
bb

and because of this requirement I need ALL date ordered by case insenstitive.

Comment: Refer the above answer

Comment: Do you have an example for a class for the service layer? 
I have the @Entity annotation in Sortiment. 
From my point of view I'll still have the case sensitive sort with your code, because it takes the standard order and not the case insensitive order.